# location.reload altering the url

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what could cause this piece of javascript to alter the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

The window location accepts fragments and changes the url from /web/page/123321 to just /web/page

Anyone ever seen anything like this before? Could it just be certain browsers?

Thanks

James

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have some old cached script or anything else in there that will do the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You're closing a php tag inside the setTimeout function.

Try this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: this should do the trick to reload a page. did you try cleaning your browser cache before trying this?

Comment: yeah, it's appearing in the error logs though (sadly no user agent string either) so having a hard time reproducing the issue. Might close it as "can't fix"

Comment: Ended up going with a window.location.assign. I think there's some toolbars out there with the ability to hijack window.location.reload... seems to have stopped the errors appearing in the logs anyway.